Faces appear translucent
While trying to flip the normals of a retopology, I noticed the mesh had become translucent and smooth, despite being shaded flat. I'm sure I hit some kind of hotkey as I had forgotten how to open the normals widget and was pressing multiple inputs to get it come up, but I have no idea how to fix this. The areas that look see-through and glassy should be solid and grey like the rest of the model. I haven't added any materials, shaders, textures, geometry nodes, etc.



You didn't hit the 'H' key in error to hide the selected faces did you? If so, just hit Alt-H to unhide them.

No, I can hide and unhide them without affecting the translucency

I think you'll have to share your Blend file in that case, preferably with just a part demonstrating the problem.  You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Done, but now when I open the file in a different instance of Blender (I use Blender through Steam but I also have the program downloaded) it renders correctly, so is it a display setting I've toggled instead of something I've done to the mesh itself?

What do you have the Clip Start and End set to on the N-panel 'View' tab in the two Blender instances?

Start and end are both set to the same parameters ( 0.01 and 1000 respectively) in both instances.

The weird shading is on the "Plane" object which has a bad set of "Custom Split Normals" data.  Select the "Plane" object, hit F3 and search for and run the "Clear Custom Split Normals Data" operator.  The shading should go back to "normal" (ha ha).

Also, the "Plane" object has Object -> Viewport Display -> In Front turned on in its properties, which will cause it show through the "MASK" object when viewed from behind; not sure if this is intended.

For whatever reason I couldn't find the option using the F3 search bar, but I found it under "Geometry Data" and it worked! Thanks!
